# How to join (merge) multiple files (by rows) using multiple columns

Tags: bash, awk, merge

I have multiple files with content like:

```
==> file1.tab <==
Contig  Position    TS-568_ALLELE   TS-568_FREQUENCY    TS-568_COVERAGE
ch00    11009393    A/C 0.02/0.97   93
ch00    11009395    A/C/T   0.01/0.97/0.01  96
ch00    11009416    A/G/T   0.12/0.83/0.04  97
ch00    11009421    A/G 0.17/0.82   97
ch00    11009427    A/C/T   0.02/0.96/0.00  101
ch01    11009436    C/T 0.99/0.00   103
ch01    11009437    G/T 0.00/0.99   104
ch02    11009441    A/G 0.07/0.92   101
ch02    11009445    G   1.0 96

==> file2.tab <==
Contig  Position    TS-602_ALLELE   TS-602_FREQUENCY    TS-602_COVERAGE
ch00    11009393    C   1.0 7
ch00    11009395    C   1.0 7
ch00    11009416    G   1.0 5
ch00    11009421    G   1.0 5
ch00    11009427    C   1.0 4
ch01    11009436    C   1.0 4
ch01    11009437    T   1.0 4
ch02    11009441    G   1.0 5
ch02    11009445    G   1.0 5

==> file3.tab <==
Contig  Position    TS-586_ALLELE   TS-586_FREQUENCY    TS-586_COVERAGE
ch00    11009393    C   1.0 34
ch00    11009395    C   1.0 35
ch00    11009416    A/G/T   0.07/0.89/0.02  39
ch00    11009421    A/G 0.10/0.89   39
ch00    11009427    A/C 0.02/0.97   37
ch01    11009436    C   1.0 44
ch01    11009437    T   1.0 44
ch02    11009441    A/G 0.06/0.93   45
ch02    11009445    G   1.0 44
```

I read about join in bash, but my problem here is that I need to join them based on two first columns, not a single one (ch00   11009427 is a unique identifier, ch01   11009427, or ch03   11009427 can also be in the list).

So, the expected output will be:

```
==> file_all.tab <==
Contig  Position    TS-568_ALLELE   TS-568_FREQUENCY    TS-568_COVERAGE TS-602_ALLELE   TS-602_FREQUENCY    TS-602_COVERAGE TS-586_ALLELE   TS-586_FREQUENCY    TS-586_COVERAGE
ch00    11009393    A/C 0.02/0.97   93  C   1.0 7   C   1.0 34
ch00    11009395    A/C/T   0.01/0.97/0.01  96  C   1.0 7   C   1.0 35
ch00    11009416    A/G/T   0.12/0.83/0.04  97  G   1.0 5   A/G/T   0.07/0.89/0.02  39
ch00    11009421    A/G 0.17/0.82   97  G   1.0 5   A/G 0.10/0.89   39
ch00    11009427    A/C/T   0.02/0.96/0.00  101 C   1.0 4   A/C 0.02/0.97   37
ch01    11009436    C/T 0.99/0.00   103 C   1.0 4   C   1.0 44
ch01    11009437    G/T 0.00/0.99   104 T   1.0 4   T   1.0 44
ch02    11009441    A/G 0.07/0.92   101 G   1.0 5   A/G 0.06/0.93   45
ch02    11009445    G   1.0 96  G   1.0 5   G   1.0 44
```

The files are sorted based on column 1 and column 2 and the number of rows are equal among them. And there are about 150 of those files with the total size of 6.5 GB

Comment: Did you try something like `join -j 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.2,1.4,1.5,2.3,2.4,2.5 file file1`?

Comment: @revo wouldn't that join only on the second field, ignoring the first? (e.g. , wouldn't two lines with `ch00 11009427` and `ch01 11009427` be joined together?)

Comment: @revo I did, but this joins all combinations of lines with the same index in column 2 so: if you have ch00 11009427 and ch01 11009427 they will appear in results twice as every combination of the lines. and what is more it is not very practical solution, if you want to join 150 files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` may achieve what you desire.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) a[$1 OFS $2]=a[$1 OFS $2] OFS $i}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}'
```

Brief explanation,

- `OFS='\t'`: set the output field separator as `\t`
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"`: Order the array by indices in ascending order compared as strings. Reference [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for more details.
- `for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) a[$1 OFS $2]=a[$1 OFS $2] OFS $i`: save the value to the specific indice in the array.
- `END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}`: print the indice and its corresponding value in the array.

Comment: Works like a charm for small files, but I have 150 files with around 1M lines each and it seem to load everything into memory before saving to file...

Comment: Actually, it worked quite well with 150 files and about 7 GB of data on a desktop PC with 16 GB of RAM! Thanks!